# Finding value of an equation using factorization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Given that $x - y$ = 1, what is the value of $ x^4- xy^3  -x^3y - 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y ^4 $?

My attempt: I noticed that $ -3x^2y + 3xy^2 $ can be factorized and become  $-3xy(x - y)$. So that the equation become $ x^4- xy^3  -x^3y - 3xy + y ^4 $. However It is not useful in solving the equation.

Comment: Why is it not useful? You might be able to find other simplifications/reductions.

Comment: In fact, having found a useful way of simplifying part of the problem, you might be inclined to be a bit more deliberate about seeing whether you can do anything similar with the rest.

Comment: Just to show how you might get there: $x^4-x^3y-3xy-xy^3+y^4=x^3(x-y)-3xy-y^3(x-y)=x^3-3xy-y^3$ and $x^3-y^3$ has a well-known factorisation $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}x^4- xy^3 -x^3y - 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y ^4&=(x-y)(x^3-3xy-y^3)\\&=(x-y)\bigl((x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)-3xy\bigr)\end{align}Therefore, if $x-y=1$,\begin{align}x^4- xy^3 -x^3y - 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y ^4&=x^2+xy+y^2-3xy\\&=x^2-2xy+y^2\\&=(x-y)^2\\&=1.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you plug in $$x=1+y$$ in the given term? For your control: the result is given by $$1$$